# Android - Best way to have fluent sprite animations without wasting heap

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, heap-memory, sprite

I am a java programmer working on an Android app right now. It will be an action game, so I need to use a lot of sprites. My animations work great, but I am struggling with memory management vs performance. I read a lot online, and nothing seems to answer my issue. **I want my sprites to run smoothly, but don't want to waste too much heap**. Here's what I tried so far:

-loading one big file, with all animations in it (walk, run, jump, etc.) into the heap: It is very fast to switch from one animation to another and from frame to frame, but the big problem is the heap size is uses. We have to load the whole image file into the heap, in bitmap, which is not efficient at all (a single file can easily go up to 10Mb). We clearly don't need to load the whole image into the RAM if we only draw one small frame on the screen?

-having separate files for each animation (one for walking, one for running, etc), and loading one file at a time, when required: It is relatively efficient in size, so we don't waste heap space. It is also very fluid in loading the given animation, since the whole animation is loaded in the heap. The big issue is when changing from one animation to another (from run to jump for instance). There is a big lag, since we need to decode (bitmapfactory.decoderesources) a new file every time we need to change animation. even if it's only 500ms, it is way too slow for a game.

**Question: What would be the best way for having fluent animations, without loading huge files into the heap?**

Thanks

Comment: If its possible to downsize your files some you could probably load it all on the heap again. What kind of file size and format are you guys using

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm trying to solve the same thing, doing full screen frame animations using approx 1000x500 at 32bits per pixel.. The heap just blows up if I try to load it all in there, and the performance is pretty slow if I just load/decode each by disk every time.